# Canvas.drawBitmap performance on Android 4.3

Tags: android, performance, drawing, android-canvas, drawbitmap

I have two Samsung S4, one is 4.2.2, the other 4.3. I am running the same game, which is drawn on SurfaceView. On 4.2.2 drawing takes about 30ms, while on 4.3 almost 100ms. Drawing is performed from the other thread. I have checked, that the problem is with drawBitmap method. Any suggestion how to fix it? The problem appears only on S4 with Android 4.3. I also checked on Nexus 7 with 4.4.2, everything is ok.

Comment: Do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: I use similar code to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295615/low-fps-with-android-surfaceview ,in view.onDraw(c) I just draw full screen bitmap with some buttons (bitmaps). I checked the performance and the problem is with drawBitmap method and drawing, game engine is ok. Game runs faster even on old phones like HTC desire Z.